# Roundcube: AUTHENTICATION PLAIN: Authentication failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

I installed Postfix, Dovecot, Roundcube, Postfixadmin on Amazon EC2 Linux.

I configured Postfix, Dovecot, Roundcube and Postfixadmin one-by-one, and I can create new mailbox via Postfixadmin. However, I cannot login the newly created mailbox via Roundcube. The Roundcube log shows:

> IMAP Error: Login failed for info@domain.com from 11.22.33.44. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/html/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 193 (POST /roundcube/?_task=login&_action=login)

And for the `/var/log/maillog`, it shows:

> ip-172-31-13-226 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=

The Dovecot Config is changed as follow ( `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` ) :

```
protocols = imap lmtp
dict {
}
!include conf.d/*.conf
!include_try local.conf
```

And for `conf.d/10-mail.conf` :

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace inbox {
}
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

And for `conf.d/10-master.conf` :

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
  }
}
service imap {
}
service pop3 {
}
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}
service auth-worker {
}
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
  }
}
```

for `conf.d/10-auth.conf` :

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

Last, for `conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext` :

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

So, what did I config wrong that leads to login failure?

---

After enabling `auth_debug = yes` and `auth_verbose = yes`, here is the log shown in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=12671)
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0111#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=2vyhVho0cgB/AAAB#011lip=127.0.0.1#011rip=127.0.0.1#011lport=143#011rport=49266#011resp=<hidden>
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth-worker(12673): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth-worker(12673): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth-worker(12673): Debug: pam(info@domain.com,127.0.0.1): lookup service=dovecot
May 31 02:43:30 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth-worker(12673): Debug: pam(info@domain.com,127.0.0.1): #1/1 style=1 msg=Password: 
May 31 02:43:32 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth-worker(12673): pam(info@domain.com,127.0.0.1): unknown user
May 31 02:43:34 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0111#011user=info@domain.com
May 31 02:43:34 ip-11-22-33-44 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<info@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<2vyhVho0cgB/AAAB>
```

"Unknown User" error occurred. Seems Dovecot / Roundcube are not reading the same user database. How can I make sure they read the same user database?

Comment: Does this `!include ` mean that include is commented out?

Comment: no. `!include` means including the files if they exist. Commenting out starts with `#`. See [this](http://wiki.dovecot.org/BasicConfiguration)

Comment: Try to enable `auth_debug=yes`. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging

Comment: Added the debug message in question, can you please help? thanks.

Comment: So `passdb { driver = pam }`, the user name should be `info` (without @domain.com).